# Android volley gives BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 415

Tags: android, json, rest, android-volley

While doing a POST request with android volley, My serverside consumes json type in request header, I am facing error 415. Though i have set the headers here by overriding getHeaders method, I am facing this unusual error while making the request. 
can any body help me here? 
I have also provided the source code below:

```
 private void registerUser( final String email,
                                  final String password) {
            // Tag used to cancel the request

            String tag_string_req = "req_register";

            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            showDialog();

            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                    AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {



                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                        if (!error) {
                            // User successfully stored in MySQL
                            // Now store the user in sqlite
                            String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                            JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                            String email = user.getString("email");
                            String created_at = user
                                    .getString("created_at");

                            // Inserting row in users table
                            db.addUser(email, uid, created_at);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            // Launch login activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    RegisterActivity.this,
                                    LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {

                            // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                            // message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {


                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Posting params to register url
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    //params.put("name", name);
                    params.put("email", email);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return headers;
                }


            };

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
        }
```

Comment: server response code 415 is `Unsupported Media Type`. check your server side.

Comment: My server side is ok. It consumes json type request. is there anything wrong with my code? @ELITE